# decode hex pcap packet in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

There is a pcap hex packet in the following format:

```
0000   D4 C3 B2 A1 02 00 04 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0010   FF FF 00 00 01 00 00 00  5F D0 4C 59 57 D6 0E 00   ........_.LYW...
0020   84 00 00 00 84 00 00 00  00 00 C2 85 C1 03 00 00   ................
0030   00 00 00 02 81 00 00 0A  08 00 45 00 00 6E E4 C4   ..........E..n..
0040   00 00 FF 06 C7 AF 01 02  03 04 0A 01 01 0F 00 10   ................
0050   00 0A 00 01 E2 40 00 03  94 47 50 10 10 00 D2 F8   .....@...GP.....
0060   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0070   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0080   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0090   00 00 00 00 3B C5 9A 8F  38 A4 2B 76 7D 39 7A 68   ....;...8.+v}9zh
00a0   8A 59 F6 A4 CC 32 C7 97  B1 86 F6 50               .Y...2.....P
```

The byte `00 00 C2 85 C1 03` which starts from 0x0025 is my real packet, the pcap packet has a 0x25=37 bytes header, I wonder how to decode this packet in `scapy` in python. It didn't work to decode it directly in the following code:

```
load_packet = Ether(raw_packet)
print load_packet.src, load_packet.dst
print load_packet.getlayer(IP).src, load_packet.getlayer(IP).dst
print load_packet.getlayer(TCP).sport, load_packet.getlayer().dport
```

where `raw_packet` is the above packet string.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little ugly(to be honest a **lot**), but it works.
Just put the hexdump in a file called `stack_overflow` and run the script below.
I've tested it using python3.5,

```
from scapy.all import *
import sys

def fix_packet(in_file, out_file, offset_to_start):
    '''
    Create a new hexdump text file without the bytes that need to be skipped

    in_file: hexdump file to read from
    out_file: hexdump file to write to
    offset_to_start: how many bytes (in decimal) to skip until the strat of the actual packet
    '''
    hex_data_to_store = []
    ascii_data_to_store = []

    for line in open(in_file, 'r').readlines():
        ascii_data = line.strip().split('   ')[len(line.split('   ')) - 1]
        hex_data = line.strip().split('   ')[1].split('   ')[0].replace(' ', '')

        if not offset_to_start:
            hex_data_to_store.append(hex_data)
            ascii_data_to_store.append(ascii_data)
        else:
            if offset_to_start - len(ascii_data) >= 0:
                offset_to_start -= len(ascii_data)
            else:
                hex_data_to_store.append(hex_data[32 - ((len(ascii_data) - offset_to_start) * 2)::])
                ascii_data_to_store.append(ascii_data[16 - (len(ascii_data) - offset_to_start)::])
                offset_to_start = 0

    hex_data_to_store = ''.join(hex_data_to_store)
    ascii_data_to_store = ''.join(ascii_data_to_store)

    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        index = 0
        while True:
            if len(ascii_data_to_store) >= 16:
                f.write('{:04x} {} {}\n'.format(index, ' '.join('{}{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in zip(hex_data_to_store[:32:2],
                  hex_data_to_store[1:32:2])),
                  ascii_data_to_store[:16]))
                hex_data_to_store = hex_data_to_store[32::]
                ascii_data_to_store = ascii_data_to_store[16::]
            else:
                f.write('{:04x} {} {}{}\n'.format(index,
                  ' '.join('{}{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in zip(hex_data_to_store[::2], hex_data_to_store[1::2])),
                  '   '*(16 - len(ascii_data_to_store)), ascii_data_to_store[:]))
                break
            index += 16

def write_data(data):
    '''
    This is a trick because import_hexcap reads the hexdump from the stding
    '''
    with open('new_file', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
        f.write(chr(4))

def read_hex():
    old_stdin = sys.stdin
    sys.stdin = open('new_file', 'r')
    pkt=Ether(import_hexcap())
    sys.stdin = old_stdin
    return pkt

fix_packet(in_file='stack_overflow', out_file='new_hex', offset_to_start=40)
hex_str = [x.strip() for x in open('new_hex', 'r').readlines()]
write_data('\n'.join(hex_str))
load_packet=read_hex()
print(load_packet.src, load_packet.dst)
print(load_packet.getlayer(IP).src, load_packet.getlayer(IP).dst)
print(load_packet.getlayer(TCP).sport, load_packet.getlayer(TCP).dport)
```

I got the following output:

```
>>> print(load_packet.src, load_packet.dst)
00:00:00:00:00:02 00:00:c2:85:c1:03

>>> print(load_packet.getlayer(IP).src, load_packet.getlayer(IP).dst)
1.2.3.4 10.1.1.15

>>> print(load_packet.getlayer(TCP).sport, load_packet.getlayer(TCP).dport)
16 10
```